# Spring export schema DDL to the database in runtime

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Dynamic **DataSource** in my Spring Boot application.

The problem is I need to generate tables from my entities. There is a way with

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

but it doesn't work for me since I need to connect to Database in run-time.
What I need to know is can I call some method to do same things as Spring does on application startup with mentioned option.

Comment: for the record, that property is only asking Hibernate to do its thing so Spring Boot doesn't do anything special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey after some research I found the answer. All you need is to ask **sessionFactoryBuilder** to generate update scripts for your database and execute than with **JdbcTemplate**.

```
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.scanPackages("su");
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    try{
        List<SchemaUpdateScript> scripts = sessionFactory.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList(new PostgreSQL9Dialect(),
                new DatabaseMetadata(dataSource.getConnection(), new PostgreSQL9Dialect(), sessionFactory));
        log.info("Schema update scripts["+scripts.size()+"]");
        for (SchemaUpdateScript script:scripts ) {
            log.info(script.getScript());
            jdbcTemplate.execute(script.getScript());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error("error updating schema",e);
    }
```